# Upgrade from 4.6 to 4.72 DB error - no such field

Tags: upgrade

As I was following the process to upgrade to 4.72, I received the following error when updating the DB:

```
[Error: Upgrade DB to 4.7.beta8]
Error Field Error Value
Type    DB_Error
Code    -19
Message DB Error: no such field
Mode    16
UserInfo    UPDATE civicrm_payment_processor_type SET is_active = 0 WHERE name = 'Google_Checkout' [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'payment_instrument_id' in 'field list']
DebugInfo   UPDATE civicrm_payment_processor_type SET is_active = 0 WHERE name = 'Google_Checkout' [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'payment_instrument_id' in 'field list']
```

I still very new to Civi and I'm not sure where to begin with this other than rollback to my backup. I've attached a full screenshot as well. Thanks for any help in advance.

Jason[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just did an Upgrade from Civicrm 4.6.11 to 4.7.2 - (plan copy) which went without any error - so please try the below and update the result

Just TEST This First 
I guess you had Payment processor enabled in your previous version and which has extra column for the payment processor type

So please try to Roll back to your previous version of CiviCRM 4.6 first

Then try to delete the payment processor or Disable the payment processor and try to Upgrade to Civicrm 4.7.2

Also if possible try to disable all the extension too.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be caused by triggers which CiviCRM is adding to the database during the upgrade.

I had a problem that fits this description exactly, except on Joomla! (your screenshots appear to be from WordPress), when upgrading from 4.6.21 to 4.7.12. After exploring lots of different possibilities related to MySQL triggers, I was able to complete the upgrade by simply  disabling the "Logging" option under Administer > System Settings > Misc. This setting makes use of triggers to perform the logging, and those triggers were interfering with the upgrade. After the upgrade is complete, I can re-enable logging again with no problem.

Interestingly, some older upgrade instructions like this one for Drupal https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC42/Upgrade+Drupal+Sites+to+4.2+-+Drupal+7#UpgradeDrupalSitesto4.2-Drupal7-5.DisableLogging specifically say "disable logging", but there doesn't seem to be any mention of this requirement after 4.2, nor anywhere that I could find for Joomla! or WordPress.

Comment: This worked for me. After restoring the database, I disabled logging and deleted the triggers for good measure, and then the upgrade ran all the way from 4.6.38 to 5.7.5. I re-enabled logging, the previous logging information is still there, and the triggers are rebuilt.